# Disposing objects - how correctly print base type on the screen

Tags: c#, resources, dispose, idisposable

I am following MSDN guideline of [implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720161%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). I've written my simple code to better understand and run the code step by step.

**EDITED**: changed title to better fit the problem

This is the code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Base0 base0 = new Base0();
        base0.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Sub1 sub1 = new Sub1();
        sub1.Dispose();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Base0 : IDisposable {
    private bool disposed;
    public Base0() {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Base0!");
        this.disposed = false;
        // allocating some resources
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing " + this.GetType().ToString() + "!");
        if (!this.disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                // disposing all managed resources
            }
            // disposing all unmanaged resources
        }
    }
    public void DoSomething() {
        if (this.disposed) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
    ~Base0() {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
class Sub1 : Base0 {
    private bool disposed;
    public Sub1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Sub1!");
        this.disposed = false;
        // allocating some resources
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing " + this.GetType().ToString() + "!");
        if (!this.disposed) {
            try {
                if (disposing) {
                    // disposing all managed resources
                }
                // disposing all unmanaged resources
            }
            finally {
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Creating Base0!  
Disposing DisposeFinalizeMethods.Base0!  

Creating Base0!  
Creating Sub1!  
Disposing DisposeFinalizeMethods.Sub1!  
Disposing DisposeFinalizeMethods.Sub1!
```

I am confused because I expected that the last line would be saying "Diposing ... Base0!", the base type.

The code executes as it should, I've checked it 'step by step' many times, I understand it but there is something that I've missed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is not about Dispose or IDisposable but about GetType.

`this.GetType()` is a call to a virtual method. When called in a base-class it will give the Type of the actual (derived) type.

To reproduce:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.Write(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.Write(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}


        var b = new B();
        b.Print();
```

Will print `BB`.

Comment: So.. The only way to see the whole 'disposing path' on the screen  is to hardcode Console.WriteLine("Disposing ActualType!") inside each overriden Dispose method? The same way as I did with constructors?

Comment: I know, it works, but I want to know "is this the only way" :-)

Comment: @dygi: Take a peek at my answer using generics.  That will work without a hard-coded string, and would thus work with automatic refactoring.  It could be used anywhere in the code, including in your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

As the **caller (type that calls)** object is of type `Sub1` you will see it two times.

This is virtual method so calling on base class `GetType` will return **caller's** type

It's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `typeof(Base0)` in Base0's Dispose method. GetType always returns the type that was actually instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the compile-time type of a parameter, it may be helpful to use the generic method illustrated below:

```
    static class typeGetter
    {
        static Type getKnownType<T>(this T it) where T : class
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
        static String test()
        {
            IEnumerable<System.IO.Stream> myThing = new List<System.IO.MemoryStream>();
            return String.Format("Run-time type {0} but compile-time type {1}",myThing.GetType().ToString(),myThing.getKnownType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Evaluating test() will yield (line-break added for readability)

```
"Run-time type System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.IO.MemoryStream] but
  compile-time type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.IO.Stream]"
```

The getKnownType method will return the compile-time type of the variable or expression that's passed to it, even if the object in question happens to have a more deeply derived type at run-time.